Why does space change when using custom font in Monaco editor on web?
We are attempting to create a browser-based IDE from scratch, using the Monaco editor. To make this project more unique, we are using a custom font in the editor for code. When the user tries to select text in the editor, it gets squished together. Why does this happen, and is there any way to make it stop?
We tried changing the custom styling code for the Monaco editor, but nothing changes. Part of the code is below, and the rest is at https://github.com/thejupitergroup/WebCode
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor'), {
                language: 'html',
                theme: 'vs-dark',
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: "normal",
                fontFamily: 'Priffordd Mono, TwemojiRubisco, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                scrollBeyondLastLine: true,
                minimap: { enabled: true },
                lineNumbers: "on",
                wordWrap: "off"
            });


Try monaco.editor.remeasureFonts(); once your editor is mounted.

Thank you for your answer. We tried it and it didn't change anything.
